# TextClock auto refreshed after a while

Tags: android

I am new to Android development, and I have this weird problem. I am using Android Studio to program.

I have this activity that displays a TimePickerDialog when the user clicks on *alarmTime* TextClock, and when he sets the desired time, it will be displayed in the same TextClock. The problem is after a few seconds, the TextClock 'forgets' the time been set and displays the current time.

N.B. The TextClock displays current time by default (when initialized).

XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.zboot.zalarm.NewAlarmActivity">

    <TextClock
        android:id="@+id/alarmTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Java code

```
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextClock;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import java.text.DateFormat;

public class NewAlarmActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_alarm);
        this.setTitle("New Alarm");

        final boolean is24HourFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(this);

        final TextClock alarmTime = (TextClock) findViewById(R.id.alarmTime);
        final DateFormat timeFormat = DateFormat.getTimeInstance();
        alarmTime.setText(timeFormat.format(System.currentTimeMillis()));

        final TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int h, int m) {
                String hour = "" + (is24HourFormat ? h : ((h == 0 || h== 12) ? 12 : h%12));
                String min = m>9 ? "" + m : "0" + m;
                String ap = is24HourFormat ? "" : (h<12 ? "AM" : "PM");
                alarmTime.setText(hour + ":" + min + " " + ap);
            }
        }, 12,0,is24HourFormat);

        alarmTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                timePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? please help.

Comment: I don't see anything with that code that would do what you describe. I'm not familiar with TextClock but I suspect there must be more code than that.

Comment: Yes there is some more code, but I think it has not to do with that, or could it? The other code contains some radio boxes and buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextClock is new to me, so I wasn't sure what it does. I took a quick look at the [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/TextClock.java) and it seems that TextClock spawns a thread that continuously updates the text to the current time. All you can do is change its formatting, but it's really, just as its name implies, a clock. From the docs:

> TextClock can display the current date and/or time as a formatted
> string.

So I think you should stop using TextClock and just use TextView instead.

EDIT: If there's something you like about TextClock, you may want to just copy the source code (see link above), make your own TextClock (AlarmClock?) and just remove the Runnable that keeps updating the current time.